# C++ function (de)duplication in templatized classes

Tags: c++, optimization, templates

Please have a look at this code snippet:

```
template<int N> class Foo {
public:
    int f() { return N; }
    int g() { return 0; }
};

Foo<3> a;
Foo<4> b;
```

I think it's compiler dependent, but, in general, will two different instances of `g()` be generated for `a` and for `b` or will the compiler recognize that it does not depend on the template parameters and generate only one instance?

Comment: Just guessing, but I think the compiler *has* to create two completely different instances. Because function pointers etc. will be different, so if it would unify, for example the functions, it would change behaviour of the program (e.g. comparing if `&a.f == &b.f`).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I didn't think of this. See my own answer where I have tried it with g++ and it's as you say.

Comment: Here is a two year old discussion on the same: [GCC(/Clang): Merging functions with identical instructions (COMDAT folding)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168924/gcc-clang-merging-functions-with-identical-instructions-comdat-folding)

Comment: Another question on same, which brings up a C++ standards issue: [Do distinct functions have distinct addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533740/do-distinct-functions-have-distinct-addresses) Note that this is being debated and the situations could change. According to these links, MSVC does it, GCC gold linker with `--icf` does it, provided that there is no attempt to take the pointer address of these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can depend on this happening with current compilers.

Rather than the `g_aux()` suggested in the comments, you might consider using inheritance:

```
class base { 
public:
    int g() { return 0; }
};

template <int N>
class Foo : public base {
public:
    int f() { return N; }
};
```

With this it's still possible that the compiler could generate inline code for `g` if it's simple enough, but based on your comments I doubt that's really a concern. Without inlining...well, `g()` is one member of one class, so we can expect essentially every compiler to generate exactly one copy of it.

Since this isn't intended to allow conversion to the base class, the theoretically correct way of doing it would probably be to make `g()` a protected member function, use private inheritance, and add `using base::g;` to the derived class to make `g()` (and only g, not the base class itself) visible to the outside world:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
protected:
    int g() { return 0; }
};

template <int N>
class Foo : private base {
public:
    using base::g;
    int f() { return N; }
};

int main() {
    Foo<3> a;
    Foo<4> b;

    std::cout << a.g() << "\n" << b.g() << "\n"; // <-- no problem

    // base *c = &a; // <-- fails
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution without much hope for my old compiler. I thought it wouldn't accept the `using base::g;` part, but it did. Thanks, I'm going to experiment with it in my existing code to see if I can reduce the code size in a significant manner.

Comment: @ToniHomedesiSaun: The `using base:g;` syntax has been around for a long time..seems like it was added around 1995 or so. I'd be worried about anybody using a compiler old enough that it didn't support this (but if you need to work with such an ancient beast, there's a way to do the job with it as well by re-declaring the function).

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with g++

```
/* prova.cpp */
template<int N> class Foo {
public:
    int f() { return N; }
    int g() { return 0; }
};

int bar() {
    Foo<3> a;
    Foo<4> b;

    return a.g() + b.g(); /* Required to force the compiler to generate the functions */
}
```

running:

```
g++ -c prova.cpp && objdump -sS prova.o
```

and it effectively generates two different `g()` functions with identical content.

Comment: And if you put compiler optimization on it wil just result in no Foo classes at all and a bar function returning 0. This is what happens with a lot of template code because it allows the compiler to optimize really agressively.

Comment: @Teimpz: True, but this is just an example. In my real life problem g() is so complex it won't get optimized... The only trick I can think of is having a single friend function g_aux() and make g() be a simple proxy call to g_aux(). Just a pity C++ can't do this on it's own